# Почему на гитхабе на MacOS X чекбоксы в Хроме меняют фон при масштабировании?

Tags: вёрстка, google-chrome, macos, масштабирование

Открываем на Mac OS X в Хроме задачу на гитхабе (для примера): https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/14348

Чекбоксы выглядят так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но достаточно немного изменить масштаб страницы (например, нажимаем `⌘ и +`), и они приобретают серый фон:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит?